# Cypress Testing fetch element attributes

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have just started working on a new testing project to add Cypress tests for an ExtJS application. ExtJS uses dynamic ids so we are using different selectors to identfy elements.

Now, if I use simple Javascript, I can fetch poperties and call methods of the element selected as shown below:

```
ele = document.getElementById('tdscombo-1108')
<div class=​"x-field x-form-item x-form-item-default x-form-type-text x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" role=​"presentation" id=​"tdscombo-1108" data-cy=​"broadcast_type" style=​"width:​ 625px;​">​…​</div>​

ele.id
'tdscombo-1108'

ele.role
'presentation'

ele.style
CSSStyleDeclaration {0: 'width', accentColor: '', additiveSymbols: '', alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', …}`

ele.getAttribute('data-cy')
'broadcast_type'
```

When working with Cypress and using cy.get to do the same,
`cy.get('[data-cy="broadcast_type"]').invoke('attr','data-cy')`
and
`cy.get('[data-cy="broadcast_type"]').its('data-cy')`
both return a Cypress $Chainer object. I don't know what that is.

The closest I have come is running
`cy.get('[data-cy="broadcast_type"]').then((elem) => {Object.values(elem[0].attributes).forEach((v) => {console.log(v)})});`
which gives me

```
class=​"x-field x-form-item x-form-item-default x-form-type-text x-field-default x-anchor-form-item x-field-focus"
role=​"presentation"
id=​"tdscombo-1225"
data-cy=​"broadcast_type"
style=​"width:​ 625px;​"
```

These each seem like some kind of object and I am unable to access the properties like so: `v.id`. It says `undefined`.
I just want to be able to access these properties as key-value pairs as in simple Javascript above.

[Here is the ExtJS combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjNax.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with these key-value pairs?

Comment: I want to use them to fetch the combobox's options using an ExtJS call. The ExtJS platform does not use classical html, all the elements consist of divs with Javascript used to mimic fuctionality of a combobox. Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/omrxeKVE0HhW.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you already gave the answer somewhere there, but I can clarify for you.

These are the Javascript vs jQuery vs Cypress equivalents:

```js
// getting the element

const element = document.getElementById('tdscombo-1108')  // js
const $element = Cypress.$('tdscombo-1108')               // jQuery
cy.get('#tdscombo-1108').then($element => {               // Cypress
```

```js
// getting role 

element.getAttribute('role')                                     // js
$element.attr('role')                                            // jQuery
cy.get('#tdscombo-1108').invoke('attr', 'role').then(role => {   // Cypress
```

```js
// getting width

element.style.width                                              // js
$element.css('width')                                            // jQuery
cy.get('#tdscombo-1108').invoke('css', 'width').then(width => {  // Cypress
```

If you practice some variations on a live page, you will learn the variations.